# Why is NLog WriteToNil not filtering out the specified loggers?

Tags: c#, logging, maui, nlog

I'm using NLog in a .Net MAUI app as per the instructions here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog

The logging is setup fine, no problem there. However, I want to filter out some verbose 3rd-party / Microsoft components. I followed the instructions here to do that: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API (see section `Build NLog config that restricts output from noisy logger`). However, whatever I do, the filter is not working :(

Here is my configuration:

```
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().RegisterMauiLog()
    .LoadConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout("${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:mm\\:ss} ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger}: ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}");
        SimpleLayout filename = new SimpleLayout(Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "Logs", "Log.log"));

        builder.ForLogger("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.*").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Warn);
        builder.ForLogger("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Warn);
        builder.ForLogger(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteToFile(filename, layout, Encoding.UTF8, NLog.Targets.LineEndingMode.Default, true, false, 1048576, 3, 5);
        builder.ForLogger(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteToMauiLog(layout);
        
        NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "Logs", "NLog-log.log");
        NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogLevel = NLog.LogLevel.Debug;
        NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Test").Info("Hello World");
    })
    .GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

This config produced the following output in the NLog internal log file:

```
2023-12-19 19:26:09.4116 Debug logNamePattern: (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.:StartsWith) levels: [ Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ ]
2023-12-19 19:26:09.4116 Debug logNamePattern: (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection:Equals) levels: [ Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ ]
2023-12-19 19:26:09.4116 Debug logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ File ]
2023-12-19 19:26:09.4116 Debug logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ MauiLog ]
```

This looked to me like it was only filtering levels *above* WARN for the loggers that I wanted to filter out (despite the WriteToNil arguments seeming to say that they filter everything *below* the provided level, WARN in my case). So, I tried it the other way round:

```
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().RegisterMauiLog()
    .LoadConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout("${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:mm\\:ss} ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger}: ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}");
        SimpleLayout filename = new SimpleLayout(Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "Logs", "Log.log"));

        builder.ForLogger("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.*").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Debug);
        builder.ForLogger("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Debug);
        builder.ForLogger(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteToFile(filename, layout, Encoding.UTF8, NLog.Targets.LineEndingMode.Default, true, false, 1048576, 3, 5);
        builder.ForLogger(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteToMauiLog(layout);        
        
        NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "Logs", "NLog-log.log");
        NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogLevel = NLog.LogLevel.Debug;
        NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Test").Info("Hello World");
    })
    .GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

This config produced the following output in the NLog internal log file:

```
2023-12-19 19:27:59.8683 Debug logNamePattern: (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.:StartsWith) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ ]
2023-12-19 19:27:59.8683 Debug logNamePattern: (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection:Equals) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ ]
2023-12-19 19:27:59.8683 Debug logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ File ]
2023-12-19 19:27:59.8683 Debug logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ MauiLog ]
```

This looked like it was going to filter out all levels for the loggers I was trying to get rid of, more hopeful, but alas I am still getting the non-desired loggers in my log :( For example:

```
2023-12-19 19:26:12.5523 Debug Targets configured when LogLevel >= Debug for Logger: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection
2023-12-19 19:26:12.5523 Debug Logger Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection [Debug] => File MauiLog
2023-12-19 19:26:12.5523 Debug Logger Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection [Info] => File MauiLog
2023-12-19 19:26:12.5523 Debug Logger Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection [Warn] => File MauiLog
2023-12-19 19:26:12.5523 Debug Logger Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection [Error] => File MauiLog
2023-12-19 19:26:12.5523 Debug Logger Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection [Fatal] => File MauiLog
```

Finally I thought I'd try registering the loggers in a different order:

```
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().RegisterMauiLog()
    .LoadConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout("${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:mm\\:ss} ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger}: ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}");
        SimpleLayout filename = new SimpleLayout(Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "Logs", "Log.log"));

        builder.ForLogger(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteToFile(filename, layout, Encoding.UTF8, NLog.Targets.LineEndingMode.Default, true, false, 1048576, 3, 5);
        builder.ForLogger(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteToMauiLog(layout);
        builder.ForLogger("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.*").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Debug);
        builder.ForLogger("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Debug);
        
        NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "Logs", "NLog-log.log");
        NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogLevel = NLog.LogLevel.Debug;
        NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Test").Info("Hello World");
    })
    .GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Which looks like this in the internal log:

```
2023-12-19 19:37:20.4908 Debug logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ File ]
2023-12-19 19:37:20.4908 Debug logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ MauiLog ]
2023-12-19 19:37:20.4908 Debug logNamePattern: (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.:StartsWith) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ ]
2023-12-19 19:37:20.4908 Debug logNamePattern: (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection:Equals) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ ]
```

But, I'm still getting the unwanted loggers in the log :(

At this point I'm at a bit of a loss to know what to do next. AHA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting that NLog v5.2.7 fails to report the expected LoggingRule-configuration when using `WriteToNil`, `FinalMinLevel` or `Final`.

NLog v5.2.8 has been released includes [pull-request](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/5441) that improves NLog InternalLogger output when using `FinalMinLevel`, and fixes the unexpected behavior by `ForLogger(NLog.LogLevel.Debug)`. Until having updated to the latest NLog-version, then `ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Debug)` can be used as work-around. Thus your initial configuration:

```cs
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().RegisterMauiLog()
    .LoadConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout("${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:mm\\:ss} ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger}: ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}");
        SimpleLayout filename = new SimpleLayout(Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "Logs", "Log.log"));

        builder.ForLogger("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.*").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Warn);
        builder.ForLogger("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Warn);
        builder.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteToFile(filename, layout, Encoding.UTF8, NLog.Targets.LineEndingMode.Default, true, false, 1048576, 3, 5);
        builder.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteToMauiLog(layout);        
    })
    .GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Will give the new output where LoggingRules created with `WriteToNil`, will show that LogLevels with lower severity will writeTo empty target-list.

```
logNamePattern: (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.:StartsWith) levels: [ Trace Debug Info ] writeTo: [ ] finalMinLevel: Warn
logNamePattern: (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection:Equals) levels: [ Trace Debug Info ] writeTo: [ ] finalMinLevel: Warn
logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ File ]
logNamePattern: (:All) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ MauiLog ]
```

And for a Logger with name `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection`:

```
Targets configured when LogLevel >= Debug for Logger: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection
Logger Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection [Warn] => File MauiLog
Logger Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection [Error] => File MauiLog
Logger Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection [Fatal] => File MauiLog
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! I look forward to trying it out :) However, I am slightly concerned that you have just addressed the internal log output, and not that the required filtering is not actually happening?

Comment: By that I mean that log entries for both Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.* and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection are appearing in my logs, even though the internal log seemed to imply they would be filtered out as per '2023-12-19 19:37:20.4908 Debug logNamePattern: (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.:StartsWith) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ ]
2023-12-19 19:37:20.4908 Debug logNamePattern: (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection:Equals) levels: [ Debug Info Warn Error Fatal ] writeTo: [ ]'

Comment: @Ben There are several unit-test in the NLog-project that verifies WriteToNil and FinalMinLevel are working. You are wellcome to create a [pull-request](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pulls) for the NLog-repository that shows filtering not working. Alternative create a [new issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues) and attach a sample-project that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Hi Rolf, I'm evaluating NLog just as much as I am Maui, in my own time, I'm sure you can understand that I don't have time to get into the NLog source code. I've never used NLog before. If it doesn't work as I need, then no problem, I will look elsewhere. I posted the question as I was hoping I was doing something wrong rather than it being a bug. Thanks for your time looking at my question! :)

Comment: @Ben You don't have to get into the NLog source-code. You only have to create a simple example-project that reproduces the issue with filtering not working. And then create [new issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues) where the example-project is attached. Again you first initial attempt looks correct, but the attempts afterwards to "fix" the logging that looks wrong.

Comment: @Ben Ahh now I see the issue. The `builder.ForLogger(NLog.LogLevel.Debug)` gives a bad experience. That should be fixed in the NLog-project. You can make the following work-around: `builder.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Debug)`

Comment: Hi Rolf, I tried `builder.ForLogger("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.*").FilterMinLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Error);` but I'm still getting entries in my log such as `...DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer...` . If I can't get this working in SeriLog either then I'll come back and look at formally reporting this to the NLog project. Forgive me for not wanting to do that off the bat, if I'd had loads of use out of NLog already it would be different, but this is the first time I've tried it out and right now I'm just looking for the quickest way to get my hobby project running...

Comment: @Ben Look at my answer where I have "fixed" the `LoadConfiguration` to use `FilterMinLevel`. Again I'm sorry about the bad experience, but thankful for the feedback, as it will make the next NLog-release better.

Comment: Hi Rolf, your suggested code is working perfectly, thanks! Just FYI that I copied my config from https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API section "Build NLog config that restricts output from noisy logger" which does not use FilterMinLevel in the example, interestingly the other examples on that page *do* use FilterMinLevel...

Comment: @Ben By default `ForLogger()` (without any input-parameter) means all LogLevels. The problem with calling `ForLogger(LogLevel.Debug)` has now been fixed with NLog v5.2.8 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/5.2.8 (Thanks again for highlighting the issue)

Comment: thanks for the great support! I've been very happy with NLog since this issue, above all the super configurability at run-time via code! Nice product :)